# How would I go about parsing a large zip file (MySQL .DAT file dumps) in the browser, and then sending requests to an API?

Tags: javascript, mysql, rest

I'm trying to get some info out of a zipped folder containing some .DAT files (I think they are TSV files) from a MySQL dump.

I'm using a backend-as-a-service, so ideally I'd like to just read the file, extract the relevant data from the various .DAT files in the zip, and make requests through the browser to my backend API.

I know this might take a while, or require streaming the file in chunks while processing it. Ideally the app would just show the progress and a spinner or something while it's in process.

Admittedly, I'm not very familiar with client-side file handling and what kinds of considerations are required for handling files in this manner in the browser in javascript.

Comment: Can you explain why you would ever do this in the browser, instead of server-side using normal programs that were designed to do this?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans because I'm using a "backend-as-a-service", which is a service running a rest API for a database, but one that doesn't give programmatic access to either the backend server or the underlying database, but only the rest API